# 'Gulp' não executa através do 'Git Bash'

Tags: npm, gulp, gulpjs, yarn, gulpfile

Estou tentando executar minhas tasks no Gulp através do Git Bash, porém quando dou o comando `gulp` para executar ele me trás a seguinte mensagem:

```
$ gulp
bash: gulp: command not found
```

Porém, eu consigo executar utilizando o comando `yarn run gulp`. Alguém sabe me dizer o por quê dele não executar utilizando o comando `gulp` apenas?

Comment: Ele não está na `PATH`. No CMD/PowerShell do Windows funciona?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não funciona no CMD também

Comment: Você instalou o `gulp` localmente no projeto?

Comment: @LuizFelipe instalei tanto localmente quanto no global